# Import function from submodule in __init__.py without exposing submodule

Tags: python, python-import

I' working on a Python project with a directory structure similar to this:

```
foo/
├── bar
│   ├── bar1.py
│   ├── bar2.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

Where the module `bar1` defines the function `function1`.

I would like to have users of my code import `function1` (and nothing else) directly from `foo`, i.e. via `from foo import function1`. Fair enough, that can be achieved with the following `foo/__init__.py`:

```
from .bar.bar1 import function1

__all__ = ['function1']
```

The problem now is that someone running `import foo` in e.g. the REPL will still be presented with `foo.bar` alongside `foo.function1` when trying to autocomplete `foo.`. Is there a way to "hide" the existence of `bar` from users without changing its name to `_bar`?

I might be going about this the wrong way alltogether so I'm open to suggestions on how to restructure my code but I would like to avoid renaming modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with deleting `bar` reference in `foo/__init__.py`:

```
from .bar.bar1 import function1

__all__ = ['function1']

del bar
```

[Existence of `__all__` affects the `from <module> import *` behavior only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/9609843)